# create new table - missing parenthesis

Tags: oracle11g

need to create this but its saying missing left parenthesis?

```
CREATE TABLE 
  active_units2(agency_code varchar2(10) not null,
  unit varchar2(10) not null,
  supp_unit_1 varchar2(10) not null,
  supp_unit_2 varchar2(10) not null,
  supp_unit_3 varchar2(10) not null,
  supp_reqmt varchar2(10) not null,
  alt_priority varchar2(1) not null,
  alt_group varchar2(1) not null,
  crew_type varchar2(10) not null,
  status_control varchar2(1) not null,
  onduty_status varchar2(10) not null,
  dependant_res_type varchar2(10) not null,
  mdt_state varchar2(10) not null,
  brigade int not null,
  node int not null,
  port int not null,
  breathing_apparatus int not null,
  manual_crewing int not null,
  udf1 varchar2(10) not null,
  udf2 varchar2(10) not null,
  udf3 varchar2(10) not null,
  udf4 varchar2(10) not null,
  CONSTRAINT active_units2_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (agency_code ,unit))
```

Comment: Remove 'CLUSTERED' - what are you expecting that to do? I assume it's form another DBMS but I'm not familiar with it...

Comment: thanks..working now!

Answer (score 0):

When you run that statement in SQL*Plus the output you get is:

```
  CONSTRAINT active_units2_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (agency_code ,unit))
                                          *
ERROR at line 24:
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

The `*` indicates where the problem is - not always helpful but it is in this case. The `CLUSTERED` key word isn't valid in Oracle, [as you can see from the syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJADJGEC), so you just need to remove that word.